# Como mudar o texto de um <p> dentro do php? Tem como inserir um trecho em JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, inner

Estou fazendo um cadastro em que não podem ter usuários com o mesmo nome/nick cadastrado. Para validar se há ou não uso o PHP, gostaria de saber como imprimir na tela um p com uma mensagem se já existir um usuário com aquele nome cadastrado. Tentei fazer assim, mas não dá certo

```
    if(is_null($id)){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nick, email, senha) VALUES ('$nick' , '$email' ,'$senha')";
            $q = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            $url = 'aux.php';
            echo'<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
         }
         else{
            ?>
             <script type='text/javascript'>
                 var uso = document.getElementById('emUso');
                 uso.innerHTML = 'Este nick já está em uso!'
             </script>
         <?php   
         }
```

Comment: Por esses motivos que o php tem uma má reputação. Para resolver o seu problema, procure sobre requisições Ajax em javascript. Você pode fazer uma consulta no banco para ver se já existe esse nick name toda vez que alterar o valor do input, caso retorne false, gere uma msg de erro ou algo do tipo. A forma que você esta fazendo além de ser errado, é uma má prática.

Comment: usa Ajaxassociado com bind jquery

Comment: Hmm, ok. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='text']").on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "suaurl.php",
      data: {
        'nickName': $.trim($(this).val())
      },
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response) {
      if (!response.status) {
        alert('Já existe alguém com esse nickName');
        return false;
      }
      // faça algo
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Nick name</label>
<input type="text">
```

Como não sei a arquitetura do seu projeto, se você esta trabalhando com classe ou estruturado. Vou deixar um exemplo super básico. Entenda a idea >

```
<?php
    $getNickname = getNickName($valorDoInput); // faz sua consulta
    if(count($getNickname)){ //conta o array, se for maior que 0, entra no if
       echo json_enconde(array('status' => false));// retorna status false para o Ajax
       exit;
    }
```